# Цикл выполняется и появляется результат, но выдает ошибку

Tags: python, циклы, for, tesseract

Я написал код с использованием python tesseract, который переводит номера телефонов с изображения в текст(изображения берутся со списка), и выводит их в порядковом значении:

```
for i in links:
    img = Image.open(i)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang=None, config='')
    for links in range(len(links)):
        print(str(links+1) + ". " + str(text))
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for links in range(len(links)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

но при этом код выполняется и выводится желаемый результат перед ошибкой, полностью это выглядит так

```
1. 8 921 295-18-36

2. 8 921 295-18-36

3. 8 921 295-18-36

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for links in range(len(links)):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: ты в цикле переменную с тем же именем переиспользуешь    `for links in range(len(links)):`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov
я поменял 'for links in range(len(links)):' на 'for z in range(len(links)):' и появилась ошибка     'print(str(links+1) + ". " + str(text))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list'

Comment: ```object of type 'int' has no len()``` говорит о том, что переменная ```links``` имеет тип ```int``` т.е. это число, а у числа нет длины, поэтому нельзя применить функцию ```len``` к переменной ```links```

Comment: @mark раз изменил переменную для хранения индекса с `links` на `z`, тогда и в принте используй не `links+1`, а `z+1`

Answer (score 1):

```
    for links in range(len(links)):
        ^^^^^              ^^^^^
```

После первого прохода внешнего цикла у вас в переменной `links` получается число, потому что вы эту же переменную используете во внутреннем цикле. Я, кажется, понял, что вы хотели сделать, нумерация перебираемых в цикле объектов делается с помощью встроенной функции питона `enumerate`:

```
for i, img_link in enumerate(links, 1):
    img = Image.open(img_link)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang=None, config='')
    print(str(i) + ". " + str(text))
```

В современных версиях питона последний `print` можно записать проще и понятнее:

```
    print(f'{i}. {text}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил все простым `break` в первом блоке `for`:

```
for i in links:
    img = Image.open(i)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang=None, config='')
    for links in range(len(links)):
        print(str(links+1) + ". " + str(text))
    break
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода в ответе

Comment: Но в этом случае вы обрабатываете только первый элемент списка `links`, остальные не обрабатываете